# How can I read a reqwest::Response object's bytes_stream() with an implementer of arrow_array::RecordBatchReader?

Tags: rust, apache-arrow, reqwest

I am attempting to use the `reqwest` crate to stream binary data in arrow-IPC format from a REST API endpoint out of my control. The `reqwest::Reponse` object has a `bytes_stream()` method that returns a type implementing the trait `Stream<Item = Result<Bytes>>`. I'm hoping its possible to read this as a RecordBatch stream in some way, such as with `arrow-ipc::reader::StreamReader` or some other implementer of the `arrow_array::RecordBatchReader` trait. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: The `arrow` crate doesn't seem to provide async facilities (there is an open [issue](https://github.com/apache/arrow-rs/issues/1207) about that), but the `arrow2` crate [does](https://docs.rs/arrow2/latest/arrow2/io/ipc/read/stream_async/struct.AsyncStreamReader.html). Can you switch to it?

Comment: Alternatively, is async a requirement? Perhaps you can go with blocking code.

Comment: Is it possible in principle to use both arrow and arrow2 (and I'd use arrow2 for this one task)? If not I could switch to using responses from request::blocking::Client and I'd be interested in a solution in that direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arrow` crate does not have support for async currently (although [there is an open issue for that](https://github.com/apache/arrow-rs/issues/1207)), but the alternative `arrow2` [does](https://docs.rs/arrow2/latest/arrow2/io/ipc/read/stream_async/struct.AsyncStreamReader.html), and luckily it also defines a conversion layer between its types and `arrow`'s types. So this is one option (the code is quite involved because `arrow2`'s async support requires an `AsyncRead`, but what we have is a `Stream` giving `Byte`s):

```rust
use std::io;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{ready, Context, Poll};

use arrow2::datatypes::Schema;
use arrow2::io::ipc::read::stream_async::AsyncStreamReader;
use arrow2::io::ipc::read::StreamMetadata;
use arrow2::io::ipc::IpcSchema;
use arrow_format::ipc::MetadataVersion;
use bytes::Bytes;
use futures::stream::Fuse;
use futures::{AsyncRead, Stream, StreamExt};
use reqwest::Client;

struct StreamAsAsyncRead<St> {
    stream: Fuse<St>,
    last: Option<Bytes>,
}

impl<St: Stream> StreamAsAsyncRead<St> {
    fn new(stream: St) -> Self {
        Self {
            stream: stream.fuse(),
            last: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<St: Stream<Item = reqwest::Result<Bytes>> + Unpin> AsyncRead for StreamAsAsyncRead<St> {
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut [u8],
    ) -> Poll<io::Result<usize>> {
        let this = &mut *self;
        let data = match &mut this.last {
            Some(data) if !data.is_empty() => data,
            last => {
                let Some(next_data) = ready!(this.stream.poll_next_unpin(cx)) else {
                    return Poll::Ready(Ok(0));
                };
                let next_data = next_data.map_err(|err| io::Error::other(err))?;
                last.insert(next_data)
            }
        };

        let fill_len = std::cmp::min(buf.len(), data.len());
        buf[..fill_len].copy_from_slice(&data[..fill_len]);
        data.advance(fill_len);
        Poll::Ready(Ok(fill_len))
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let response = client.get("<address>").send().await?;
    let data_metadata = StreamMetadata {
        schema: Schema::default(),
        version: MetadataVersion::V5,
        ipc_schema: IpcSchema {
            fields: Vec::new(),
            is_little_endian: true,
        },
    };
    let mut stream = AsyncStreamReader::new(
        StreamAsAsyncRead::new(response.bytes_stream()),
        data_metadata,
    );
    while let Some(item) = stream.next().await {
        let item = item?;
        for item in item.into_arrays() {
            let item = arrow::array::ArrayRef::from(item);
            // Do something with `item`.
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
arrow = "50.0.0"
reqwest = { version = "0.11.24", features = ["stream"] }
tokio = { version = "1.36.0", features = ["full"] }
bytes = "1.5.0"
futures = "0.3.30"
arrow-format = "0.8.1"
arrow2 = { version = "0.18.0", features = [
    "io_ipc",
    "io_ipc_read_async",
    "arrow",
] }
```

Another, simpler option is to give up async support and just use reqwest's blocking interface:

```rust
use arrow::ipc::reader::StreamReader;
use reqwest::blocking::Client;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let response = client.get("<address>").send()?;
    let reader = StreamReader::try_new(response, None)?;
    for item in reader {
        let item = item?;
        // Do something with `item`.
    }
    Ok(())
}
```